# ngCkeditor and Ckeditor, deploying assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, asset-pipeline, bower

i have a rails application that users bower for retreiving some assets like angular, angular-plugins and ng-Ckeditor. My main problem is the above error when i am trying to deploy my application.
I cannot find what have happened and i do think that this might be some problem with ckeditor gem and ng-ckeditor of bower.
Under the error message i will paste my production.rb, deploy, gemfile so as to tell me if you see something wrong.

```
ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: eof (undefined) (line: 11, col: 0, pos: 286)

Error

at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20140613-30493-1mkpf99js:2357:10754)
at js_error (/tmp/execjs20140613-30493-1mkpf99js:2357:10973)
at croak (/tmp/execjs20140613-30493-1mkpf99js:2357:19198)
at token_error (/tmp/execjs20140613-30493-1mkpf99js:2357:19335)
at unexpected (/tmp/execjs20140613-30493-1mkpf99js:2357:19423)
at block_ (/tmp/execjs20140613-30493-1mkpf99js:2357:24668)

at ctor.body (/tmp/execjs20140613-30493-1mkpf99js:2357:24322)
at function_ (/tmp/execjs20140613-30493-1mkpf99js:2357:24387)
at expr_atom (/tmp/execjs20140613-30493-1mkpf99js:2357:27439)

at maybe_unary (/tmp/execjs20140613-30493-1mkpf99js:2357:30108)
(in /home/******/site/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/ckeditor-84ef6a7e3ee8/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/override.js.erb)
```

Production.rb

```
config.assets.precompile << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components')
config.assets.precompile += Ckeditor.assets
```

Deploy.rb

```
before 'deploy:assets:precompile', 'deploy:assets:install'
namespace :deploy do
  namespace :assets do
    desc 'install asset dependencies'
      task :install do
      run "cd #{latest_release} && bundle exec rake bower:clean"
      run "cd #{latest_release} && bundle exec rake bower:update:prune['--config.interactive=false']"
      run "cd #{latest_release} && rm vendor/assets/bower_components/ng-ckeditor/LICENSE"
      run "cd #{latest_release} && mv vendor/assets/bower_components/ng-ckeditor/src/styles/ng-ckeditor.less vendor/assets/bower_components/ng-ckeditor/src/styles/ng-ckeditor.scss"
    end
  end
end
```

Application.js and admin/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require ckeditor/override
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require underscore-min
//= require microplugin
//= require sifter.min
//= require selectize.min
//= require isotope.pkgd.min
//= require fit-columns
//= require jquery.screwdefaultbuttonsV2
//= require fancySelect
//= require flash
//= require notifications
//= require reviews
//= require raty
//= require how
//= require teachers
//= require init
//= require angular
//= require angular-resource
//= require angular-xeditable
//= require angular-sanitize
//= require angular-bootstrap
//= require ng-ckeditor
//= require app
//= require_tree ./angular
```

**Import is that when i remove from application.js(+admin) ckeditor/override deploy finished but ckeditor of gem is not playing in contradiction to ng-ckeditor with continues to play**

I do believe that ng-ckeditor initialize its own ckeditor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that might need help with that, i resolved the issue by

`config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(mangle: false)`